# Filling a matrix based on the content of another matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to fill one matrix based on the content of another matrix. Here are the matrices:

```
set.seed(135)
MAT1 <- replicate(6, sample(c("00", "01", "10", "11", "10"))); MAT1 <- t(MAT1)
rownames(MAT1) <- rep(letters[1:3], each = 2)
MAT1

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
a "00" "01" "10" "11" "10"
a "10" "00" "01" "11" "10"
b "10" "10" "00" "11" "01"
b "11" "10" "01" "00" "10"
c "10" "00" "01" "10" "11"
c "00" "10" "11" "01" "10"

LIST <- apply(X = MAT1, MARGIN = 2, FUN = unique)
MAT2 <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 3, ncol = length(unlist(LIST)))
rownames(MAT2) <- c(letters[1:3]); colnames(MAT2) <- unlist(LIST)
MAT2 <- rbind(Hap = rep(1:length(LIST), lengths(LIST)), MAT2)
MAT2

    1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  5
Hap 00 10 11 01 00 10 10 01 00 11 11 00 10 01 10 01 11
a   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
b   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The first row (Hap) of `MAT2` (`MAT2[1,]`) contains the modalities of each column of MAT1 but with duplicate modalities removed. In `colnames(MAT2)`, 1 1 1 means for the column 1 of MAT1 there are three unique modalities, 2 2 2 means for column 2 of MAT1 there are three unique modalities, etc.
I want to fill MAT2 thanks to MAT1 so that for a given Hap and colnames it fills 0, 1 or 2 according to number of times that Hap appears in `MAT1`.
Below is the expected `MAT2`:

```
        1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  5
    Hap 00 10 11 01 00 10 10 01 00 11 11 00 10 01 10 01 11
    a   1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  0  0
    b   0  1  1  0  0  2  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
    c   1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

We split the 'MAT1' by column, loop over the `list`, get the `table` of count after `stack`ing into a two column dataset.  Then loop over the `names` of the `list` and assign the columns in 'MAT2' that matches with the same name with the extracted `list` element

```
lst1 <- lapply(asplit(MAT1, 2), function(x) as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(x)[2:1])))
names(lst1) <- seq_along(lst1)
for(nm in names(lst1)) {
      MAT2[-1, colnames(MAT2) == nm] <- as.matrix(lst1[[nm]])
 }
```

-output

```
MAT2
#     1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    5    5    5    5   
#Hap "00" "10" "11" "10" "11" "01" "10" "00" "01" "11" "01" "10" "00" "01" "10" "11" "00"
#a   "1"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "0" 
#b   "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "2"  "0"  "0"  "2"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "2"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
#c   "0"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"
```

#### data

```
MAT1 <- structure(c("00", "10", "00", "11", "10", "11", "10", "11", "10", 
"10", "10", "01", "10", "00", "01", "01", "01", "10", "11", "01", 
"10", "10", "00", "10", "01", "10", "11", "00", "11", "00"), .Dim = 6:5,
.Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), NULL))

MAT2 <- structure(c("00", NA, NA, NA, "10", NA, NA, NA, "11", NA, NA, 
NA, "10", NA, NA, NA, "11", NA, NA, NA, "01", NA, NA, NA, "10", 
NA, NA, NA, "00", NA, NA, NA, "01", NA, NA, NA, "11", NA, NA, 
NA, "01", NA, NA, NA, "10", NA, NA, NA, "00", NA, NA, NA, "01", 
NA, NA, NA, "10", NA, NA, NA, "11", NA, NA, NA, "00", NA, NA, 
NA), .Dim = c(4L, 17L), .Dimnames = list(c("Hap", "a", "b", "c"
), c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "5", "5", "5", "5")))
```

Comment: Before the loop, it works well. However, the loop doesn't fill `MAT2` as expected based on `lst1`. The second (and even other) list of `lst1` is not filled correctly in `MAT2` @akrun.

Comment: I found a way thanks to your answer to obtain MAT2. It is a bit crappy but it works.
`MAT2 <- do.call(cbind, lst1);
COLNAMES <- unlist(lapply(lst1, function(x) colnames(x)));
MAT2 <- rbind(Hap = COLNAMES, MAT2);
colnames(MAT2) <- rep(1:length(LIST), lengths(LIST))`

Comment: @AchilleNyouma it may be that your structure may be different